# How to fix body min-width in bootstrap?

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't want my app resizing and responding to sizes lower than a given width... say 960px just like Facebook Page.

I can't just do `body { min-width: 960px }` in Bootstrap because of media queries.

What can I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media (max-width: 767px) {  .site-action-buttons {
    top: -100px;
 }
.site-action .btn {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
 padding: 0;
font-size: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0 rgba(60, 60, 60, .1);
 box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0 rgba(60, 60, 60, .1);
}}
```

try something like this